# How to avoid data being stored to Page table

Tags: silverstripe

From my experience if no $db is specified when creating a new class all the data for that page type goes into the Page && SiteTree tables.

I personally find this behaviour quite messy and unorganised and would like anything defined as it's own thing to have it's own table.

Is there any way to explicitly set a new class to have and use its own table regardless if it does or doesn't have any additional fields added via $db?

Comment: Why do you think it's messy? If `SiteTree` has a `Title` and you have a Subclass (say `Page`), would you really want a table `SiteTree` with a `Title` field and a `Page` table with a `Title` field? If only `SiteTree` has the `Title` field, it matches the actual class structure more closely and allows you to change your Page to another class without losing information that is stored in the base-class table.

Comment: @bummzack I think that is a good answer to this question. Do you want to post it as an answer?

Comment: @bummzack after reading the answer below I see how I was looking at it the wrong way and because of that I saw it as being messy. You're both right, if I had done what I wanted to do then I would just have a bunch of empty tables because the `Title` & `Content` are stored elsewhere anyway (which I didn't notice as I was working mostly on custom page types that don't use `Content` and I had simply overlooked that there was no `Title` column)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any way to explicitly set a new class to have and use its own table regardless if it does or doesn't have any additional fields added via $db?

No.

Once a `DataObject` (which `SiteTree` is simply a subclass of) contains a `$db` static, then a table is created of the same name with fields on it comprising those fields you define in `$db`.

Doing anything differently would be to "break SilverStripe" and how it uses its ORM. If you create a `DataList` and dump the output of its `sql()` method, you'll see that queries for `Page` are JOINed to the `SiteTree` table. Doing this way is in fact *tidier* as you can always expect the `Title`, `Content` (etc) fields to be in the `SiteTree` table and anything custom you declare in your `Page` and `Page` subclasses, to be in their own respective table(s).

```
$sql = SiteTree::get()->filter('ClassName', 'Page')->sql();
var_dump($sql);
```

Comment: Mmm I see where you're coming from when you say it's tidier. Because I was only checking the DB when working on page types with customs fields and no content I completely missed the fact that both the `Title` and `Content` fields were not included in the table for that class. After noticing this I see how it wouldn't make any sense to have every page type have its own class since that table would just be empty anyway lol